# Disable visibility of both parent and child div together

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div box which loads on window load and slowly slides up on html click.

Problem is the child div tags inside that div are disappearing after parent div is completely disappeared. How do i make them disappear simultaneously.

Here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGnbP/)

In this fiddle i want "Sometext" to disapper with grey div. Not after it.

```
<script>

$(window).load(function() {
    $("#box").css("visibility","visible");
   e.stopPropagation();
});

$("html").click(function(e){
 $("#box").slideUp('slow', function() {$("#box").css("visibility","hidden");});

});
</script>
```

PS: Click on the Result section on grey page

Comment: Does everything need to be position: fixed?

Comment: why calling `$("#box").css("visibility","hidden");` in your callback ?

Comment: Why do you need to change visibility? They both hide when you `slideUp` anyway [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LGnbP/2/)

Comment: It would be good if it was fixed. And hidden, i was being protective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have update your jsFiddle. I accomplished the goal by adding a `style="position:absolute;"` to the div containing 'Some Text'.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siddhapura/LGnbP/1/)

Comment: Thanks hitesh, that could work. But is there any way to make this happen like a viper cleaning out the div? i.e. without shrinking?

Comment: @RohanSagar, what do you mean by viper cleaning??

Comment: I mean can it be done without shrinking while sliding up? btw thanks for solution. My question is almost solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the Style of the inner Div by this 
style='position : absolute ;'